# Is this an accurate layman's description of the Anti Foundation Axiom

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

I'm writing an article that covers as one of its topics hypersets/non-well founded sets.  In order to do so I have to describe what the anti-foundation axiom (AFA) is my description is currently as follows.

"The anti-foundation axiom is a rule that if you have a system describing what sets are elements of other sets then there is exactly one solution to this system".

Is there anything misleading about describing it this way?

Comment: It is terribly imprecise.

Comment: and it's ill-written. "... is a rule that if you..." just doesn't work, for many reasons. Axioms are not 'rules'. Even if they are, they don't mention "you", nor should you, as this "you" doesn't occur in the 'then' part. Better construction is "The AFA is an axiom which states that ...", or "stating that...". Just what it states would be anyone's guess from your rendition.

Comment: Is "anti foundation axiom" standard notation? The name alone seems like a poor choice.

Comment: @Stefan Indeed it is standard. Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom)

Comment: @Stefan: Yes. There are several variants of it (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory), too. AFA, usually refers to Aczel's axiom, which asserts that for every directed graph (or something like that) there exists a unique realization of that tree.

Comment: @Asaf Thanks, I totally misunderstood the meaning of this axiom from OP's description. Now its name makes a lot more sense to me.